# Using Sliding tabs in a fragment

Tags: android, fragment

I'm working on an app where I am supposed to fragment my MainActivity into 2 fragments. One on the right whitch going to hold some textEdits and buttons, and one on the left that should hold some sliding tabs.

I already did the fragmentation part, and added tabs on the left fragment, but the problem is I don't know how to make the tabs slide. Please I really need your help. Thanks in advance.

This is what I wrote so far:

**MainActivity=>AppActivity.java:**

```
package com.example.g514110.morphokitihm1;

import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTabHost;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;


public class AppActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_app);


        if (savedInstanceState == null) {

            getSupportFragmentManager()
                    .beginTransaction()
                    .add(R.id.main_container_1, new MainTab())
                    .commit();

            getSupportFragmentManager()
                    .beginTransaction()
                    .add(R.id.main_container_2, new StaticFragment())
                    .commit();
        }
    }

    public static class MainTab extends Fragment {

        private FragmentTabHost mTabHost;

        //Mandatory Constructor
        public MainTab() {
        }

        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        }

        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                                 Bundle savedInstanceState) {

            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_main_tab,container, false);


            mTabHost = (FragmentTabHost)rootView.findViewById(android.R.id.tabhost);
            mTabHost.setup(getActivity(), getChildFragmentManager(), R.id.realtabcontent);

            mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("fragmenta").setIndicator("Biometric operations"),
                    Tab1.class, null);

            mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("fragmentb").setIndicator("DataBase operations"),
                    Tab2.class, null);

            return rootView;
        }
    }

    public static class Tab1 extends Fragment {

        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                                 Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab1, container, false);

            return rootView;

        }
    }


    public static class Tab2 extends Fragment {

        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                                 Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab2, container, false);

            return rootView;

        }
    }

    public static class StaticFragment extends Fragment {

        private View rootView;


        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_static_frag, container, false);

            return rootView;
        }


    }
}
```

**activity_app.xml:**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" tools:context=".MainActivity">


    <LinearLayout android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:layout_width="fill_parent">
        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/main_container_1"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_width="450dp"/>
        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/main_container_2"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_width="200dp"/>
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

**activity_static_frag.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <!--Acquisition pannel-->


    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="170dp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/textview_border"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:id="@+id/relativeLayout3"
        android:layout_marginLeft="68dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="71dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/APLabel">



                <VideoView
                    android:layout_width="150dp"
                    android:layout_height="160dp"
                    android:id="@+id/videoView"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"/>


        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="30dp"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:text="@string/Sacqu"
            android:id="@+id/stop"
            android:background="@drawable/shutdown_design"
            android:src="@drawable/shutdown1"
            android:layout_column="4"
            android:layout_marginTop="170dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="130dp" />


                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="150dp"
                    android:layout_height="27dp"
                    android:text=" "
                    android:id="@+id/msg"
                    android:background="#DFDFDF"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/videoView"
                    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/videoView"
                    android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/videoView"
                    android:layout_marginTop="35dp"/>


                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="150dp"
                    android:layout_height="27dp"
                    android:text=" "
                    android:background="#DFDFDF"
                    android:id="@+id/qty"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/msg"
                    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/msg"
                    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/msg"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"/>

        <ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/qtyProgressbar"
            android:layout_width="150dp"
            android:layout_height="20dp"
            android:background="#DFDFDF"
            android:max="100"
            style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
            android:layout_below="@+id/qty"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/qty"
            android:layout_alignStart="@+id/qty"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"/>


    </RelativeLayout>


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/APLabel"
        android:layout_width="106dp"
        android:layout_height="15dp"
        android:background="@drawable/textview_border"
        android:text="@string/AP"
        android:textSize="11px"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:layout_marginLeft="100dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"/>



</RelativeLayout>
```

**activity_main_tab.xml:**

```
<android.support.v4.app.FragmentTabHost
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/item_detail_container">


        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/realtabcontent"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.v4.app.FragmentTabHost>
```

**tab1.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/item_detail_container">


    <!--Enrollement settings-->

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/textview_border"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout4"
        android:layout_marginTop="80dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="0dp">


        <CheckBox
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:text="@string/consolidation"
            android:id="@+id/cons_ch"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />


        <CheckBox
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:text="@string/SI"
            android:id="@+id/save_img_ch"/>

        <CheckBox
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:text="@string/SDB"/>


        <CheckBox
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/FFOT"
            android:id="@+id/frc_ch"/>

        <CheckBox
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/ST"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:id="@+id/save_temp_ch"/>

            <Button
                android:layout_width="110dp"
                android:layout_height="35dp"
                android:text="@string/enroll"
                android:id="@+id/enroll"
                android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                android:background="@drawable/designed_buttons"/>


    </LinearLayout>


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/APLabel"
        android:layout_width="106dp"
        android:layout_height="15dp"
        android:background="@drawable/textview_border"
        android:text="@string/ES"
        android:textSize="11px"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="65dp" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="110dp"
        android:background="@drawable/textview_border"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout6"
        android:layout_marginLeft="54dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="54dp"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/linearLayout4"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/linearLayout4"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/linearLayout4">


        <Button
            android:layout_width="110dp"
            android:layout_height="35dp"
            android:text="@string/verif"
            android:id="@+id/verif"
            android:onClick="verify"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="180dp"
            android:background="@drawable/designed_buttons"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="110dp"
            android:layout_height="35dp"
            android:text="@string/identify"
            android:id="@+id/identify"
            android:onClick="identify"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:background="@drawable/designed_buttons"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_below="@+id/verif"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/verif"
            android:layout_alignStart="@+id/verif" />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="120dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/matchingIcon"
            android:background="@drawable/matching"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />


    </RelativeLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/MOASLabel"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/textview_border"
        android:text="@string/MOAS"
        android:textSize="11px"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:layout_above="@+id/linearLayout6"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/linearLayout6"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/linearLayout6" />



</RelativeLayout>
```

**tab2.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/item_detail_container">


    <!--Database operations-->


    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:id="@+id/storageIcon"
        android:background="@drawable/stor1"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/record"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />


    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:background="@drawable/textview_border"
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout5">


                <Button
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/CreatMatch"
                    android:background="@drawable/designed_buttons"
                    android:id="@+id/matcher"
                    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

                <Button
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/NewRecord"
                    android:id="@+id/record"
                    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

                <Button
                    android:layout_width="200dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/RecordList"
                    android:id="@+id/record_list"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />



                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="20dp"
                    android:text="@string/dbsize"
                    android:id="@+id/dbSize"
                    android:textColor="#000"
                    android:layout_span="2"
                    android:layout_above="@+id/db_size"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

                <ProgressBar
                    style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="40dp"
                    android:id="@+id/db_size"
                    android:background="#DFDFDF"
                    android:layout_span="6"
                    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />



    </RelativeLayout>



</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, please read ["How do I ask a good question?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: What did you implement the tabs with? Can you post some code and perhaps a picture of the layout?

Comment: you need to use viewpager

Comment: In which xml file am I supposed to add the view pager?